# Glade C++ Linux Assistance

Tags: c++, glade

needing some help with Getting my buttons to have a click event on the second glade screen also a close even , a secondary question would be how i can arrange my Code to have both these screens on one glade UI file. thank you for any help you can give .

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>


void on_exit_btn1_clicked(GtkWidget *widget, gpointer data) {
 gtk_main_quit();
}

void open_about_dialog(GtkWidget *widget, gpointer data) {
    GtkBuilder *builder;
    GtkWidget *dialog1;
    GtkWidget *button;
    builder = gtk_builder_new_from_file("glade/about_dialog.glade");
    dialog1 = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "about_dialog"));
    button = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "exit_btn1"));
    gtk_dialog_run(GTK_DIALOG(dialog1));
    gtk_widget_destroy(dialog1);
    g_object_unref(builder);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

    GtkBuilder *builder;
    GtkWidget *window;
    GtkWidget *button;
  
    builder = gtk_builder_new_from_file("glade/main_window.glade");
    window = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "main_window"));
    button = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "show_about"));
    
    g_signal_connect(button, "clicked", G_CALLBACK(open_about_dialog), NULL);
    g_signal_connect(window, "destroy", G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);

    gtk_widget_show_all(window);
    gtk_main();

    return 0;
}
```

I've tried putting both screens on one glade UI file, but was unable to get the second screen to open with a Button click.  even an example possibly of what i need to do

Comment: Please don't apply tags without reading their description! In this case, the Linux tag doesn't make sense. Also, the title gives away very little of the problem, it just repeats the tags. As a new user here, please take the [tour] and read [ask].